# How would make this run with an if statement and one for loop?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get this to run by using an if statment, a for loop, and a list. The list is part of the parameters. I am not sure how to write the if statement and have the program loop through all of the different words and set everything how it is supposed to be.

```
newSndIdx=0;
  for i in range (8700, 12600+1):
    sampleValue=getSampleValueAt(sound, i)
    setSampleValueAt(newSnd, newSndIdx, sampleValue)
    newSndIdx +=1

  newSndIdx=newSndIdx+500
  for i in range (15700, 17600+1):
    sampleValue=getSampleValueAt(sound, i)
    setSampleValueAt(newSnd, newSndIdx, sampleValue)
    newSndIdx +=1

  newSndIdx=newSndIdx+500    
  for i in range (18750, 22350+1):
    sampleValue=getSampleValueAt(sound, i)
    setSampleValueAt(newSnd, newSndIdx, sampleValue)
    newSndIdx +=1

  newSndIdx=newSndIdx+500    
  for i in range (23700, 27250+1):
    sampleValue=getSampleValueAt(sound, i)
    setSampleValueAt(newSnd, newSndIdx, sampleValue)
    newSndIdx +=1

  newSndIdx=newSndIdx+500    
  for i in range (106950, 115300+1):
    sampleValue=getSampleValueAt(sound, i)
    setSampleValueAt(newSnd, newSndIdx, sampleValue)
    newSndIdx+=1
```

Comment: Be a little more specific please. What's your problem about, and what do you expect from your program?

Comment: This is too vague of a description. Does it not run already? Why do you need to use an `if`, a `for loop`, and `list`? What are they for? What are these `different words` and what do you need to set?

Comment: this already works but i'm trying to condense it down to an if statement and one for loop. the for loop would run through all the different ranges and do exactly what this program already does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about (no if needed):

```
ranges = (
    (8700, 12600),
    (15700, 17600),
    (18750, 22350),
    (23700, 27250),
    (106950, 115300),
)

newSndIdx = 0

for start, end in ranges:
    for i in range(start, end + 1):
        sampleValue = getSampleValueAt(sound, i)
        setSampleValueAt(newSnd, newSndIdx, sampleValue)
        newSndIdx += 1
    newSndIdx += 500
```

Comment: thank you this works, but it only plays back one word (that i can hear)

Comment: I think you want `newSndIdx += 500`, not `= 500`. This way, it's overwriting the same part of the track with each new segment, instead of leaving a gap between the segments.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you're looking for here. If so, it's pretty clumsy; the way GaretJax redesigned it is a lot simpler and clearer (and a little more efficient, to boot). But it is doable:

```
# Put the ranges in a list:
ranges = [
    (8700, 12600),
    (15700, 17600),
    (18750, 22350),
    (23700, 27250),
    (106950, 115300),
]

newSndIdx = 0

# Write a single for loop over the whole range:
for i in range(number_of_samples):
    # If the song is in any of the ranges:
    if any(r[0] <= i <= r[1] for r in ranges):
        # Do the work that's the same for each range:
        sampleValue=getSampleValueAt(sound, i)
        setSampleValueAt(newSnd, newSndIdx, sampleValue)
        newSndIdx +=1
```

However, this is still missing the bit where you add 500 for each range; to do that, you'll need another `if`, like:

```
    if any(r[0] <= i <= r[1] for r in ranges):
        if any(r[0] == i for r in ranges[1:]):
            newSndIdx += 500
        # The other stuff above
```